# Rails devise add fields to registration form when having STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, single-table-inheritance

Here is my models:

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :worker, :class_name => 'Worker', :foreign_key => :worker_id
  devise :database_authenticatable
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :worker
  attr_accessible  :worker_id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :workers_attributes, :worker_attributes, :name, :worker
end
class Worker < User
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable
belongs_to :user
attr_accessible :name, :worker, :workers
end
```

I am trying to add the field name to the registretion form at 
http://localhost:3000/workers/sign_up

**The sign up form**

```
<h2>Create Worker</h2>
<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name) do |f| %>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
 <table summary="Subject form fields">
      <tr>
        <th>Name:</th>
        <td><%= f.text_field :name %></td>
      </tr>
         <tr>
  <th><%= f.label :email %></th>
   <td><%= f.text_field :email %></td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
  <th><%= f.label :kodeord %></th>
  <td><%= f.password_field :password %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <th><%= f.label :bekraeft_kodeord %></th>
  <td><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></td>
  </tr>
   </table>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create Worker" %></p>
<% end %>
<%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

**But i get a template error: Model Worker does not respond to name**
And how do i create the association between User and Worker?

Best regards, 
Rails beginner

Comment: Are there different kinds of user? Do you need Single table inheritance? Do you need to access a worker through: user.worker? Just for me to understand your question better.

Comment: I need a STI to be able to have one single login form that Workers and Companies can both use. I relly want to be able to display diffrent views for Workers and Companies. Then i properly need to access a worker through user.worker. In my routes.rb i have devise_for :users, :companies, :workers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope I understand well: I think you haven't understand the STI concept yet.

Let's try to make it clearer.

The classes you derive from an orinal model inherits everything from it. Your original model should look like this:

```
class User <  ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me    
end
```

To really be a STI, you've to generate a migration to include "type" to your model. Simply type:

```
rails g migration add_type_to_users type:string
rake db:migrate
```

Then set up you worker model which is really simple:

```
class Worker < User
end
```

As you made, include in your routes.rb file:

```
devise_for :users, :companies, :workers
```

Now you're done!

Go to workers/sign_up, create an account and the go back to your terminal.

From here, type `rails c` to start the console.

Now try:  `User.all.last`, you should see the account you just created with a 'worker' type

And try: `Worker.last`, here again, you find the latest account created.

Please remember: Rails is as great as simple :)

Comment: thanks for this answer. It has certainly helped me understand a bit better but i have a couple of Qs. What is the point of the type in the users class, is it used internally by Devise? With Worker extending User, in which controller would he handle the extra fields (Worker vs User)? Would it not be possible to have Devise generate out both (worker/company) and then use devise_for without the need for the user class? thanks a ton!

Comment: 'type' is filled automatically by Rails, it's part of the STI process, so nothing about Devise there. All classes share the same fields: they are STI (S for Single, T for Table). I is for inheritance so you need User class: it's the root.