# Identifying the relationship with multiple one-to-one relationships between two models in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship

I have the following two models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_one :start_date, :class_name => 'KeyDate', :dependent => :destroy
 has_one :end_date, :class_name => 'KeyDate', :dependent => :destroy
```

and

```
class KeyDate < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :project
```

Given a certain key date from the database related to a project:

```
@key_date = KeyDate.find(:first)
```

is there a way to introspect the relationship to check if the @key_date is related to the project as start_date or as end_date?

Comment: I don't understand.. KeyDate is not associated with the Project model through a belongs_to association. Is :conference referencing the Project model?

Comment: Hi Sam, you're right, I pasted the wrong association, now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One clean way to do what you want is to create STI:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

See one example I gave here:

[Rails devise add fields to registration form when having STI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660106/rails-devise-add-fields-to-registration-form-when-having-sti/4662124#4662124)

Answer (score 1):

A nice way would be to use **single table inheritance** for the `KeyDate` class

```
class KeyDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class StartDate < KeyDate
end

class EndDate < KeyDate
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :start_date, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one :end_date, :dependent => :destroy
end

class CreateKeyDatesMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :key_dates do |t|
      t.date :date
      t.string :type #this is the magic column that activates single table inheritance
      t.references :project
    end
  end
  …
end
```

this lets you do

```
@key_date = KeyDate.find(:first)
@key_date.type # => "StartDate"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. This works nicely. I marked apneadiving's suggestion as the right one, as he was the first to suggest the STI solution. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking aloud...

```
class KeyDate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def start_date?
    project.start_date == self
  end

  def end_date?
    project.start_date == self
  end

  date_type
    [:start_date, :end_date].find {|sym| send("#{sym}?") }
  end
end
```

To be honest I can't see why you'd ever need this. Surely you're always going to have a handle on a project anyway?